# How to install couchdb 0.10 on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-8.04, couchdb

How to install couchdb 0.10 on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS ?

I get an error : erlang wrong version ...

Comment: so your actual question should be "which version of Erlang does CouchDB 0.10 require", then?

Answer (score 1):

I just did this install myself recently.  The Erlang included in Hardy is too old.  Simple as that.  You need to build Erlang as well as CouchDB.

1. Make sure to remove the packaged erlang first.
2. Grab erlang here: http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/lang/erlang/download.html I used R13B02-1, but whatever the latest is should work.
3. Configure with `--enable-threads --enable-smp-support --enable-kernel-poll --enable-hipe`.  I compiled it without any of that and Couch died immediately on startup.  I think the threads is the important one for Couch, but all those seemed like good ideas.
4. `make && sudo make install`

And then go build Couch the same way you were already trying.  Should work ok now.

Comment: I'm sure you could download the Erlang packages from karmic and install them manually, or use apt pinning, or whatever.  There are lots of other ways to do it if you want to use packages.  If you're going to do that, you might as well install CouchDB too and forget about building any of it yourself.  I rather like building stuff myself, so this is my preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

[Build CouchDB](https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb) builds an independent, isolated CouchDB system with all its dependencies. All you need is GCC and Rake. If you have a bug building on 8.04 and I will post a fix. Nearly every distro and version is supported already.